# Insert value after analysing 2 cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I have a sheet that will a tick box in column J.  When another tick box is ticked in column E I would like the sheet to check if column J has a tick in it and if so insert the value of 1.5 into column F.  If the tick box in J is unticked I would like the value of 3 to go into column F instead.  I have been trying to write this myself and failing so I thought I would ask the experts.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: off course: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koiunBlMWy4c3WTzbpMkKql-2Ahx9L8bYWzH0F71QMc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(J1=TRUE, IF(E1=TRUE, 1.5, 3), )
```

or perhaps:

```
=IF(E1=TRUE, IF(J1=TRUE, 1.5, 3), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Petrect!  Thank you so much